# How to stop all DB queries if one fails

Tags: php

When a user submits a form, I have 3 database actions that happen. If one fails, I don't want any of them to execute. With my current code that isn't happening. For example, if I purposefully misspell something in the SQL query the second query will fail but the first one will work and that record will be updated. How can I change this so if one fails, no changes are made at all to the database?

```
public function editAccom($data)
    {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE `accommodation` SET `name` = :name, `description` = :description, `slug` = :slug WHERE `id` = :id LIMIT 1");
        $this->db->bind(":name", $data['name']);
        $this->db->bind(":id", $data['id']);
        $this->db->bind(":description", $data['description']);
        $this->db->bind(":slug", $data['slug']);
        if($this->db->execute() === false) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM `accom_pics` WHERE `accom_id` = :id");
        $this->db->bind(":id", $data['id']);
        if($this->db->execute() === false) {
            return false;
        }

        foreach($data['pics'] as $pic) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `accom_pics` (`accom_id`, `pic_name`) VALUES (:accom_id, :pic_name)");
            $this->db->bind(":accom_id", $data['id']);
            $this->db->bind(":pic_name", $pic);

            if($this->db->execute() === false) {
            return false;

            } 
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need DB transactions:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

This way you can rollback all the latest queries if something fails.